# How to create Jar and execute it correctly

Tags: java

I have following directory structure and files:

```
Folder
    +
    |--/org
    |--Online.java
    |--Online.class
```

When I execute following code:

```
C:\>cd Folder
C:\Folder>java Online http://www.google.com google.html
```

My files execute and give me correct output as per my requirement.

Now, I want to add the package 'org' and Online.class file in one Jar file say E.g. Online.jar

I did that by executing following code:

```
jar cvf Online.jar *
```

Now, when i am trying to execute following code:

```
java -jar Online.jar http://www.google.com google.html
```

It's shows me error:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from Online.jar
```

Can any one help me out here? I want to know What is wrong here ?

Comment: I am new to Java. Can any one Help me out...Thanks in advance

Comment: A .jar is just a .zip file with a specific structure and .class files in it.

Comment: You need to have a Manifest file (google it).

Comment: If you are using eclipse or netbeans you can right click on the package and then export as jar.

Comment: @StackOverflowException - java -jar will generate a default manifest file.

Comment: @Bob Flannigon: But it wont have the Main-Class attribute correctly set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look java tutorial page:
[Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: In short: create a folder META-INF (uppercase) and therein MANIFEST.MF with `Manifest-Version: 1.0` line break `Main-Class: Online`.

Comment: @popalka This document helped me a lot and understand in details.
Thanks for providing me the link.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you build your jar. You will need a Manifest file with the main class name

I usually use a ant to build, so my build task looks like this:

```
    <target name="Build_myjar">
        <jar destfile="my.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyMainClass"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="bin"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

Notice the Manifest already has the MainClass Name, hence that takes care of invoking the MainClass

Comment: Thanks it helped me to build my ant script

Answer (score 1):

I think the default manifest may need to be modified to include the main-class...

```
  Main-Class: Online.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your FQCN is org.Online (which is a bit awkward) the structure should be:

```
Folder
    +
    |--org
    |    +
    |    |--Online.class
    |
    |--META-INF
         +
         |--MANIFEST.MF
```

That is:

- You don't have to include Online.java.
- Place the class file Online.class under the package directory org.
- Include META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

The contents of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF should be:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.Online
```

That is, specify the fully-qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the command `jar -cmf MANIFEST_FILE jarfile.jar *.class` and specify a custom Manifest file as I get the same errors as you do.

This is the simple Manifest File I use, ([src](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html))

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: MainClassName
```

> Warning: The manifest must end with a new line or carriage return. The
>   last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new
>   line or carriage return.

When running, I use `java -jar jarfile.jar` or just double click the .jar on Windows.